# JavaCC got Lexical error when lookahead meet end of file

Tags: javacc, regex-lookarounds

Why do JavaCC always give an error on terminal with lookahead? Like on this example,

```
options{
    LOOKAHEAD = 2;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(GS)
    public class GS{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
            GS parser = new GS(System.in);
            parser.q0();
        }
    }
PARSER_END(GS)

void q0():
{}
{
    "a" q1() |
    "c" 
}

void q1():
{}
{
    "b" q0()
    | "b"
}
```

On q1() there're 2 options, one is to read "b" and move to q0, or read "b" and end the reading. But if I give an input "ab" it will give an error even though it have lookahead option. But if I give "(ab)*c", JavaCC accept it just fine.

```
Exception in thread "main" TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 3.  Encountered: "\r" (13), after : ""
```

This same error always happen when the production rule is

```
{
    "terminal_x" non-terminal()
    | "terminal_x"
}
```

Is there any way to make this kind of production rule without giving an error?

I'm using JavaCC ver. 6.0_1.

thanks.

edit:

Apparently, if the production rule is in the form

```
{
    "terminal_x"
    | "terminal_x" non-terminal()
}
```

The error wont happened. But still, what cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input string contains a return character that the lexer is not expecting.  It has nothing to do with lookhahead; lookahead has to do with parsing, not lexing.  I'd suggest putting in a rule something like this.

```
SKIP : { " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" }
```

Comment: I see, my bad. Thanks this works for me. 
Though if I give the input directly from command prompt, it keep waiting for input. Is there any method to tell that the reading is finished?

Comment: On UNIX or Mac, use cntl-d.  On DOS  or Windows use cntl-z.  This will be lexed as an EOF token.

Answer (score 0):

The example rule you have suggested:

```
    {
        "terminal_x"
        | "terminal_x" non-terminal()
    }
```

is effectively saying "there must be `"terminal_x"` followed by either zero or one `non-terminal()`". This would be done easier by using the `?` operator (zero or one) as below:

```
    {
        "terminal_x" (non-terminal())?
    }
```

This way, the lookahead is not needed as it will always look for `"terminal_x"` and then allow either zero or one `"non-terminal()"`, eliminating the problem completely.

Comment: yes, that form is simpler, but the error still appear.